# Best way to update field of entity that depends of another field in the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Im looking for the best way of doing the following thing. I have an entity with this two fields:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person person;


@Column(name = "person_name")
private String personName;
```

I need that every time I persist or update this entity, it sets automatically personName with the field name of the entity Person.

I know you could use @PreSave and @PreUpdate and do something like this:

```
@PreSave
@PreUpdate
public void setName(){
this.personName=this.persona.getName();
}
```

But I was wondering if exists something more "clever", I mean, something like an hibernate annotation that require less code.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would just do this in the `setPerson()` method.